# Error in loop applying the color to SVG path based on ID using Javascript and

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, svg

Below is the code that I use to load colors to the svg map that I have based on the winning party taken from a spreadsheet with an array. The problem that I am currently facing is that there is an error in the loop and it identified only the first nine paths and applied the color and left the rest. Can someone help me identify and fix these issues. I am still learning from my mistakes and help would be appreciated.

```
<![CDATA[

 var resultData = [];
 var uniqueparty= [];
var wincolor = [];
    $.getJSON("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1IoNqeReOPKNFrYMlK2rnJVuMaLeAgnZneLbKYSQ7bs4/od6/public/values?alt=json", function(data) {
      var len = data.feed.entry.length;

      for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
         //first row "title" column
        var current = data.feed.entry[i];
        resultData[i]= [
          current.gsx$constituency.$t, //0
          current.gsx$winner2010.$t, //1
          current.gsx$winningparty.$t, //2
          current.gsx$candidatename1.$t, //3
          current.gsx$party1.$t,//4
          current.gsx$candidatename2.$t,//5
          current.gsx$party2.$t,//6
          current.gsx$candidatename3.$t,//7
          current.gsx$party3.$t//8
        ]; 
//Moving Winning party names alone to an array
wincolor[i]=[current.gsx$winningparty.$t];
      }
//Remove duplicates from the winning party array to another array
uniqueparty = wincolor.filter(function (el) {
        if (this[el]) {
          this[el] = 1;
            return el;
        }

        return true;
    }, {});
//uniqueparty.sort();

//Specify colors for the party
var colors = ["#FE9A2E", "#F2F5A9", "#81F781", "#F2F5A9", "#58ACFA", "#F3F781", "#F5A9F2", "#81F7F3", "#F5A9A9"];

//assign color using loop based on element ID
for(i=0; i<wincolor.length; i++){
  for(j=0; j<uniqueparty.length; j++){
    if(uniqueparty[j]==resultData[i][2]){

      var paths = document.getElementById(resultData[i][0]);
      paths.style.fill=colors[j];
      break;
    }
  }
}

 });
]]>
```

I have included the spreadsheet from which the data is retreived and also the svg map

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IoNqeReOPKNFrYMlK2rnJVuMaLeAgnZneLbKYSQ7bs4/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true

http://jsfiddle.net/diviseed/3ncos0uk/1/